# Retrieving JSON from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want fetch the below `data-persondetals` JSON using JavaScript or jQuery. I cannot access it using `data()` or a javascript attribute function. It always returns empty.

```
<div class="xgt_full_member_details" data-persondetails="{" skill_01":"skill="" 01="" title","skill_01_percent":"60","skill_02":"skill="" 02="" title","skill_02_percent":"","skill_03":"skill="" 03="" title","skill_03_percent":"","skill_04":"skill="" 04="" title","skill_04_percent":""}"=""></div>
```

Comment: You need to escape the double-quotes in the JSON string. Use `\"` instead of `"` (Or, which would be a lot easier, use single quotes for the attribute itself.)

Comment: Then you need to use valid JSON, as you have a lot of syntax errors; unmatched quotes, missing commas, no keys, `=` where they shouldn't be etc. Then you can simply use jQuery's `data()` method to retrieve the object.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (xg-team-script.js?ver=1.0.0:9)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

Comment: i have an array of data this one below i have to pass it trough html data attributes like i did here

    $skill['skill_01'] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'xgt_team_slider_skill_1',true);
    $skill['skill_01_percent'] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'xgt_team_slider_skill_1_percent',true);

data-personDetails='<?php echo json_encode($skill)?>'

Comment: That's not an array.  PHP has the concept of associative arrays.  Javascript does not.  Associative arrays that are encoded to json become objects.

Comment: First format your data correctly. This isn't valid JSON. Second, revisit how `$.data()` is used. Third, post your attempts to retrieve this data. Fourth, that's not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to escape double quotes in your json or wrap it around single quotes.
2. then, get youe data using

`let persondetailsJSON = JSON.parse($('.xgt_full_member_details').attr("data-persondetails"))`

EDIT: 3. use correct JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to escape the json, otherwise, the HTML will not work.
Second thing, read the data attribute.

`JSON.parse(document.querySelector('xgt_full_member_details').dataset.personaldetails);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: `data()` will auto parse the json if it is properly formatted.

Comment: I'm not using JQuery, it's vanilla JS